# Need to Align Line Directions Normals Along Specific Coord in APDL

Tags: applied-mechanics, beam, ansys, meshing

In Preprocessor of APDL, I have built areas which are meshed with shell element and lines meshed with beam elements.

I have assigned Sections to Beam elements but when I view them their cross sections are flipped due to Line normals flipping.

I want all lines to become **aligned** to that specific Coord. And I don't want to manually pick the lines.

`LDIR` is not working for me as it reverses all the lines together leaving the issue as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Shell element orientation is defined by normal, because it only has two faces. However, beam element has a section, whose orientation has to be aligned. Switching line orientation might flip the section, but not align it into a desired orientation. The section is basically 2D and it has a principal axis, which can be aligned either using coordinate system axis or using a point (or a node) which is not lying on the element axis. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ygqdwGKQw0&ab_channel=MikeFoster) with instructions how to do so.

You may also benefit from looking into *ANSYS Mechanical APDL Modeling and
Meshing Guide*, part *Generating a Beam Mesh With Orientation Nodes*.

Comment: Line normals are set by ANSYS during line creation process even before shell mesh creation. Along a particular Axis direction, ANSYS assigns Positive or Negative Axis direction on its own. I just want it to follow **Only either Positive or Only negative** (base on the chosen Coord Axis).

Comment: The line orientation might depend on the order of point picking during the creation (if created using points). If the area is a directly created rectangle, the lines orientations are such that they go around the area in the loop. When dealing with non-planar areas, individual line orientation might affect resulting area shape.

Comment: Lines are automatically created through Areas which are planar rectangle. Yes, they belong to loops and hence turn opposite in juxtaposed loops. 
Now, we want to modify their normals to get aligned to any particular Axis we give to Co-Axial lines. That is the main issue.

Comment: I believe you are mixing two issues together. One is line orientation and the other is beam section alignment. Every line has an orientation and you can flip it similarly to a shell normal. However, when you want to align beam section, you need to specify that differently. One way is shown in the video, and I think it can also be done during meshing. What you need for this is a node or a point not lying on the line (mathematical), so a normal to the APDL line (mathematical segment) can actually by defined.

Comment: Yes. Section orientation is defined by that KP but it is governed first by **Line Direction**. Thats why i have to manually change Line Normals to Align them to become **Unidirectional**. Currently, ANSYS generates lines that are Co-linear but flipped resulting in Sections flipped and finally requiring me manually Re-orientate each line.

Comment: I simply want to make selected set of lines become **Unidirectional** without requiring individual picking each time.

Comment: So your goal is really not properly aligned beam sections, you just want to make a set of line **unidirectional**? What is it for then? It is possible it can be done, however you would need to write APDL script for that. Although I am not sure if you can get current line orientation into a parameter. I would suggest trying something similar to **a = NELEM(23, 2)** which assignes global number node 2 of element 23 into parameter **a**. There might be something similar for lines, returning keypoints in ordered manner depending on the diction (which you can then check and flip if necessary).